# Unable To Run Docker In Interactive Mode in Azure (Windows) VM

Tags: azure, docker, virtual-machine

Trying to learn container (Docker) by running an interactive mode on Azure (windows) VM. The problem is no matter what I've tried I'm stuck with this:

Service 'w3svc' has been stopped

Service 'w3svc' started

[image]

Following are info I think are relevant (please correct me if I'm wrong) and things I've tried:

According to Docker Hub here are the requirement to install [Docker Desktop on Windows](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/).

[image]

I think it meets the requirements:

The Azure (windows) VM is a D4s_v3; the important thing here is that it's a v3 ( that means it supports Hyper-V)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Was able to install Docker Desktop successfully and it's a Windows container:

[image]

Was successfully in pulling two Microsoft base images:

[image]

Have tried running these commands as Admin either in PowerShell or Command line:

```
docker run -it 1202696d4a85 cmd
docker run -it microsoft/iis cmd
docker run -it mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore/iis cmd

docker run -it 1202696d4a85 --entrypoint cmd
docker run -it microsoft/iis --entrypoint cmd
docker run -it mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore/iis --entrypoint cmd
```

and we're stuck with this:
[image]

However, these two commands:

```
docker run -it 755f6d13fa75 cmd
docker run -it 755f6d13fa75 --entrypoint cmd
```

we get this error that tells us that the host and container OS are not compatible:

[image]

Is this a misleading error? Thought "Windows Sever 2019 DataCenter" is Server Core? And if it's the Desktop Experience it would have specified?

Also, when creating the VM on Azure there's no 'Server Core' option:

[image]

So, what do we need to do so that we can run in interactive mode?

TIA!

[Update]
Based on the suggestions below created a new Azure Windows 10 Pro VM.

[image]

[image]

Ran these two commands:

```
docker run -it 1202696d4a85 cmd
docker run -it 1202696d4a85 --entrypoint cmd
```

Same issue.

Comment: Which Windows OS do you choose?

Comment: @CharlesXu, the VM is a "Windows Sever 2019 DataCenter".

Comment: Maybe you can try the Windows 10 pro.

Comment: As you can see in the System Requirement for Docker Desktop: "Windows 10". You are using Windows Server, so this cannot work

Comment: alright; I'll try Windows 10 Pro in the next 24 hours and let you guys know how it goes. Thanks!

Comment: Any more questions? Do you solve the problem with the Windows 10?

Comment: @CharlesXu, created new Windows 10 Pro VM and still same issue. Please see updated question above.

Comment: I saw the error shows the container operating system does not match the host operating system. Is that the problem? Do you try to switch for it in the docker server setting?

Comment: @CharlesXu, the IIS images pulled does not work. So, pulled another image: docker run mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019. and this time I could get to the command prompt inside the container.

Comment: @CharlesXu, same on the Windows server -- cannot go to command prompt on the IIS images, but then pulled another Windows based image and can go into command prompt. Thanks for your help!

Comment: So you use another windows image without server core and it works well?

Comment: I used another image that's not IIS, but is server core and it works in both Windows 10 Pro and Windows 2019 server. Thanks!

Comment: If you solve the problem, please add the answer to show the solution, it may help others searching for it.

Comment: @CharlesXu, sorry for the late reply, the problem has not been solved. I can run docker host on Windows 10 and Windows server 2019, so it's not exclusive to Windows 10. I'm continuing to explorer container (docker) with Azure. Thanks!